# digital complements

Tags: digital

what is the application of complements such as 1's complement and 2's complement?

Comment: Huh? I don't understand what you are talking about.

Answer (score 5):

To express negative numbers in binary format.

Answer (score 2):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement):

> The two's complement of the number
>   then behaves like the negative of the
>   original number in most arithmetic,
>   and it can coexist with positive
>   numbers in a natural way.